# How does the communication between Smartwatch and Smartphone work over the same Wifi?

Tags: wi-fi

I'm building a test setup, where I want to load some data from a server, which is based in my local wifi network. I already wrote every piece of code I need, but one question came up on which I couldn't find an answer so far.

**When I have connected my phone and my smartwatch to the same Wifi, will the watch communicate directly over the wifi with the phone OR will the watch talk to the phone over the google servers?**

This is a crucial question, because my test wifi doensn't have access to the internet and therefore communication with the google server is impossible. I can't test it myself because I don't have a smartwatch that supports wifi so far.

I know this is a very technical question, but I don't think this question belongs to stackoverflow.com. This is why I ask here.

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With GPS and offline music support, you can already leave your phone
>   at home, then go jogging and jamming like normal. Now Android Wear
>   supports watches with built-in Wi-Fi. As long as your watch is
>   connected to a Wi-Fi network, and your phone has a data connection
>   (wherever it is), you’ll be able to get notifications, send messages,
>   and use all your favorite apps. And if you really do forget your
>   phone, you can always ask your watch where it is.

[From this link.](http://officialandroid.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-wear-wear-what-you-want-get.html)
I hope this text answers your question.

Comment: Hi and thank's for your answer. No, this doesn't answer my question. My qeustion is (as mentioned in my post): When I have connected my phone and my smartwatch to the same Wifi, will the watch communicate directly over the wifi with the phone OR will the watch talk to the phone over the google servers?

Comment: They "talk" over the cloud... Not by connecting on the same Wi-Fi.

Comment: So this is always the case, even if there are on the same Wi-Fi? Any links?

Comment: [Here](http://developer.android.com/wear/images/wear_cloud_node.png) you go. The exception is Bluetooth.